# Why can't npx prisma db push find my prisma schema?

Tags: database, database-schema, prisma, planetscale, t3

I'm trying to setup my first t3 app and I have no idea how prisma works. Trying to set up my database following a tutorial and **I cannot get my prisma schema to push.** I follow the tutorial *precisely* and it still doesn't work.

**Command:**

$`npx prisma db push`

**Error:**

`Error: 'could not find a schema.prisma file that is required for this command'...but my prisma file exists.`

**Code:**

Database is created on planetscale. Directory setup using create-t3-app.

schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ['referentialIntegrity']
}

datasource db {
    provider = "mysql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
    referentialIntegrity = "prisma"
}

model Example {
    id        String   @id @default(cuid())
    name String
    checked Boolean
}
```

.env

```
# When adding additional environment variables, the schema in "/src/env.mjs"
# should be updated accordingly.

# Prisma
# https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls#env
DATABASE_URL=mysql://mekxxh8g4nqmo6262jnc:**********@us-east.connect.psdb.cloud/mikes-first-crappy-db?sslaccept=strict
```

package.json:

```
"prisma": {
    "schema": "./prisma/schema.prisma"
  }
```

**Solutions I have tried and have not worked:**

This site [recommends updating the json.](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema#prisma-schema-file-location) I have tried this but I still cannot push my schema. I have also tried wrapping my DATABASE_URL in double, single, and no quotes. I have installed the prisma@4.10.1 package. None of these have worked for me. Just not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to pass the schema file location while invoking `npx prisma db push` command.

```
npx prisma db push --schema='/location/to/schema.prisma'
```

Also, I would recommend you to run the command from root location of your project.

Here's a [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#examples-6) for db push command.

Comment: I was not in the root location, so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

**npx prisma db push** not working or not responding with next js

Try shutting down the other server of next js and then again run **npx prisma db push**.
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Use the relationMode = "prisma" in your schema.prisma file in /prisma folder**

Also, in newer updates of prisma, referentialIntergrity id added to generalized and need not be specified. Delete **previewFeatures = ['referentialIntegrity']** and **referentialIntegrity = "prisma"** from *generator client* and *datasource db*

Your schema.prisma file should look like this:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Category {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid())
  name      String 
  checked   Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your database connection url (DATABASE_URL) is in .env, not .env.local (or some other env file). The default configuration pulls the environment variables from .env file.

I was getting this error, and it took a few minutes of searching to figure it out. (Yes, even with the specific solution in line 1 of the image!)

[image: Prisma db push error]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is if you are not doing the command

```
npx prisma db push
```

inside the proper folder. I was doing one level above the server and it was throwing this error.